# Apply jQuery to one of 3 divs with the same class

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple div's with the same class and I have some jQuery, but I only want to apply the jQuery to one of the div's with the class `animated`

Here is my jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
        x = $('.animated').offset().top - 100;
    if (y > x) {
        $('.animated').addClass('fadeInUp').removeClass('fadeOutDown');
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what your issue is.

Comment: add ids to them or if they are in fixed order, select it by the order, or use the mystical selector, what read your mind

Comment: Use this in your selector: `:eq(n)`.

Comment: Which is the class that is the same? It is `animated` or is it another one?

Comment: .animated is the class that is the same yes.

Comment: <<but I only want to apply the jQuery to one of the div's with the class>> But which DIV??? Depending of scrolling position or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add an id and use that as a selector or give that div another class say 'class2' and then use that. If you add a class that div would look like this:

```
<div class="animated class2"></div>
```

And then the jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
 x = $('.class2').offset().top -100;
if (y > x) {
 $('.class2').addClass('fadeInUp').removeClass('fadeOutDown');
}
```

Or if you use an id

```
<div id="myId" class="animated"></div>
```

And then the jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
 x = $('#myId').offset().top -100;
if (y > x) {
 $('#myId').addClass('fadeInUp').removeClass('fadeOutDown');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more class to that div like

```
Class="animated Operation"
```

then use this operation in jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
x = $('.Operation').offset().top -100;
if (y > x) {
$('.Operation').addClass('fadeInUp').removeClass('fadeOutDown');
}
```